# how can I get referenced original file name at minifilter When I did 'save as'?

Tags: windows, kernel, minifilter, filter-driver

I made solution that block save & saveas by file name using minifilter driver.

save blocking is OK, but I can't block saveas by file name.

I expected to get the original name from 'PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA' or 'PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA' at IRP_MJ_WRITE.

how can I get referenced original file name at minifilter When I did 'save as'?

Comment: what is *save as* ? what is *original file name* ?

Comment: @RbMm If I save a.txt as b.txt in the notepad, is there a way to get the original a.txt path, as I can get only b.txt from the prewrite of the mini filter?

Comment: of course no any way. you not save *a.txt*. you simply write some data to *b.txt*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to get original file name directly, but you can try ways below.

1. Track IRP_MJ_READ of original file per process.

   Once a process read your original file, the process can't not write any file until it's terminated.
2. Moniter [Save as] Dialog in User Mode like below.

   - Find [Save as] dialog by

     HWND hWnd = ::FindWindow("#32770", "Save As");
   - Enumerate sub windows and check class name and get  original file path from their window name.

     Text of window whose class name is 'ToolbarWindow32' contains a parent directory path of original file.

     Text of window whose class name is 'Edit' contains a name of original file.
   - Cancel [Save As] dialog by

     ::PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDCANCEL, BN_CLICKED), NULL);

Comment: If you need a strict security for your file, Use 1. Otherwise you can  consider to Use 2.